# How to know the exact path of the updated information of the firebase-database from cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

[This is my firebase-database structure (click here).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu5nY.png)

If I listen to the path */users/{uid}/*. If I insert data in */users/{uid}/GyroScope Y-axis/* or */users/{uid}/GyroScope Z-axis/*, How do I know where the data is inserted exactly? Like how do I get the reference where the data is inserted/updated?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are listening to `/users/{uid}` you will always receive updates at that level -- so `event.data.ref` and `event.data.adminRef` will be references at `/users/<THE_UID_OF_THE_WRITE>`.

To get more specific, there are a few different places you can look for more information:

1. [Event#params](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Event#params): You can call `event.params.uid` to get the `{uid}` from your example.
2. You can use the [DeltaSnapshot#previous](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot#previous) method to look at the data from before the write. So if you want to know what was written, you could diff `event.data.val()` and `event.data.previous.val()` or call `event.data.changed('GyroScope-Z-Axis')` to see if that specific property has changed.
3. You could listen at a deeper level with something like `/users/{uid}/{prop}` and then you would receive write notifications for every subproperty, not just the top level. With this pattern, your example would have a write of `event.params.prop` equal to `GyroScope Z-Axis`.
4. You could listen to e.g. `/users/{uid}/GyroScope-Z-Axis` to only get notified of that specific property.

Hope that provides you with plenty of potential avenues of attack. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for that. From my databse structure, is there any way to iterate childs under GyroScope X-axis in reverse order since newly updated information is getting placed in the last?

Comment: Firebase does not have a way to query in reverse order. Your options are a) use `limitToLast(n)` and reverse the result yourself or b) create sorting keys that explicitly sort in a negative order implicitly.